# Are the two definitions of a sufficient statistic equivalent?

Tags: sufficient-statistics

I am confused about the fundamental definition of a sufficient statistic. I found two different definitions and I wounder if they are equal.

with

- data $X$
- sufficient statistics $t$
- parameter $\theta$

**Definition 1**, e.g. from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Mathematical_definition):
"A statistic $t = T(X)$ is sufficient for underlying parameter $\theta$ precisely if the conditional probability distribution of the data $X$, given the statistic $t = T(X)$, does not depend on the parameter $\theta$.", i.e. as formula:
$$
p(X \mid t) = p(X \mid t, \theta)
$$

**Definition 2**, e.g. from a [video by Ben Lambert](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5j4E2FRR384):
$$
p(\theta \mid t) = p(\theta \mid X)
$$

- The second definition should be equivalent to $p(\theta \mid t, X) = p(\theta \mid t)$: from $t=T(X)$ we can compute $t$ from $X$, so $p(\theta\mid X) = p(\theta \mid X, t)$. Is this correct? If yes then in the two definitions the $X$ and $\theta$ are exchanged.

So, my question is: Are the two definitions equivalent (in general or under some assumptions)?  Do I overlook something?

P.S.: The second definition makes more sense if I look at the estimation of $\theta$ (estimator $\hat \theta$) from the data: $X \rightarrow \hat \theta$ and with the sufficient statistics $X \rightarrow t \rightarrow \hat \theta$. The arrows are not causal, e.g., the arrows do not reflect the data generating process which is probably $\theta \rightarrow X$, but not intermediated by a sufficient statistic(?).

The first definition also makes sense: $t$ captures all the information about $\theta$ for $X$.

Comment: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/339075/how-does-bayesian-sufficiency-relate-to-frequentist-sufficiency